# Debugging slow Quickbooks in multi-user mode

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, rdp, quickbooks

Building 1: Main QB server with 15 users
Building 2: 12 users accessing the QB server

There is no sluggishness in building 1. Building 2 has issues. They can RDP to the server fine with no lag but when they access directly with QB it runs slow. We upgraded their server we also dropped the WAN/VPN setup and went directly to a LAN(based on what we read QB works horrible over VPNs and WAN links, true?) hoping that would fix the issue but it is still acting up.

Is this a network issue or something that needs tweaking on QB or completing changing how we operate.

Comment: Tell us about what the network infrastructure hardware is inside and connecting the buildings.

Comment: What ping times are you seeing to the QB server from building 2?  Is access to a company file on the QB server from building 2 in single-user mode also slow?

Comment: 1) What version of QuickBooks is this? 2) What OS is the QB server running on? 3) What OS(es) are the client computers? 4) What is the bandwidth of the link between buildings 1 and 2?